# django restframework how to edit POST form

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

im working on api that resizes images. I want to upload just one file save it and resize and keep it in another folder.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django_resized import ResizedImageField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="files/")
    file1 = models.ImageField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.file:
            self.file1 = ResizedImageField(self.file, size=[200, 200])
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Image
from .serializers import ImageSerializer


class ListCreateImage(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Image.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        kwargs = {"author": self.request.user}

        serializer.save(**kwargs)


class DetailImage(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Image.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Image


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ("file", "file1")
        read_only_fields = (
            "id",
            "author",
        )
```

Problem is that my code works, but HTML form asks me for 2 files, I want to have the same result using just one file.

So the output should look like that:

```
{
        "file": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/register_og.png",
        "file1": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/thumb200px/register_og.jpg"
    },
```

Comment: Add file1 to `read_only_fields` if it's supposed to be read-only

Answer (score 0):

In your Meta class of the `ImageSerializer` there is a fields attribute. It should only contain the files you want to upload.

```
fields ("file")
```

not

```
fields ("file", "file1")
```

Going of your intention in the comment I suggest you also add the `"file1"` to the read only fields

```
read_only_fields = (
            "id",
            "author",
            "file1",
        )
```

Comment: It also removes file1 from JSON, my purpose is to have file1 in JSON, but not in input